# Wrapping an AsyncRead

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I can't seem to get the compiler to let me wrap a Tokio AsyncRead:

```rust
use std::io::Result;
use core::pin::Pin;
use core::task::{Context, Poll};

use tokio::io::AsyncRead;

struct Wrapper<T: AsyncRead>{
    inner: T
}

impl<T: AsyncRead> AsyncRead for Wrapper<T> {
    fn poll_read(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut [u8]
    ) -> Poll<Result<usize>> {
        self.inner.poll_read(cx, buf)
    }
}
```

This seems like it should compile but the compiler complains that I didn't include the proper trait bound even though `poll_read` is available through AsyncRead: [Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1c8857239d69fd1eb83fd43147917179)

```
error[E0599]: no method named `poll_read` found for type parameter `T` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:17:20
   |
17 |         self.inner.poll_read(cx, buf)
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `T`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the type parameter is bounded by the trait
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Look at `self` in the signature for `poll_read`:

```rust
fn poll_read(
    self: Pin<&mut Self>, // Self is pinned!
    cx: &mut Context,
    buf: &mut [u8]
) -> Poll<Result<usize>>
```

Self is pinned, meaning that `poll_read` can only be called on `Pin<&mut T>`'s! `self.inner` is of type `T` which is why the compiler cannot find `poll_read` on it. To fix this we have to somehow get pinned access to the field.

There's a [whole section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html#pinning-is-structural-for-field) of the Rust `Pin` documentation on this and a [whole crate](https://crates.io/crates/pin-project) dedicated to solving this issue.